Options to address this venting issue where the washing machine pulls the water from the shower p-trap
I installed a drain pump system because our washer would never drain the water up fully and left the clothes gross. While the pump works amazing it now forces so much water through the 1.5" pipe is sucks the p-trap of the connected shower dry every-time it drains. Given the setup I have what's the easiest/best solution to this problem?
My idea is to run a new pipe from the washing machine so it's not tied to the tub at all but I'm not sure where to connect it and if I should run a vent with it too.



